# Selenium ChromeDriver does not open new web browser but gets the page source

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

Environment Details:

`selenium==3.141.0
Google Chrome 73.0.3683.103
Driver Used -- 73.0.3683.68 -- chromedriver_linux64.zip
OS -- Linux 16.04
Python -- 3.5.2`

In the above environment, my code runs successfully and gets the page source. However, it does not open a new web browser like automated QA testing.

I am not sure if I am missing something here. I have also tried with Firefox (GeckoDriver).

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import time

options = Options()
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path=r'/usr/local/bin/chromedriver')

driver.get('https://www.google.com')
driver.maximize_window()
print(driver.page_source)
driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

It does open a new *ChromeDriver* and *Chrome Browsing* session but as you are using the *argument* **`--headless`** through an instance of `ChromeOptions` the *browsing window* isn't visible.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @DebanjanB.But if remove the headless and sandbox options, I get the following error selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)  (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=73.0.3683.68 (47787ec04b6e38e22703e856e101e840b65afe72),platform=Linux 4.4.0-17134-Microsoft x86_64)

Comment: I have updated my question now, that was posted my mistake.

Comment: _...WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally..._ is a different question altogether and you need to raise a new question for your new requirement.